# DateTime issues with Azure c#, javascript, sql....so confused.

Tags: asp.net, json, datetime, timezone

Alright, so my website allows people to store their work schedules.  They enter their shift starting datetime and ending datetime.  Simple enough, right?

The idea is I can look at the site and see Bob's working in Chicago tonight from 4-6pm, and Joe's working in New York from 8-10pm.  And that's how I want the dates displayed in the app.  If I'm viewing the site from California, I still want to display Chicago times for Bob, and New York times for Joe.  I do NOT want to convert those times to California times where it'd show Bob working from 2-4pm, and Joe working from 5-7pm.

My site has sample data and when everything's located in the same timezone it's fine, but I've now deployed it to Azure servers in North Central US (It uses SQL Azure located there as well, although I'm unclear on where there is), and now the date and times are all off (jumped forward by 7 hours).

I believe the reason for this is that I use a lot of Ajax and JSON, and JSON requires datetimes to be formatted like this /Date(1240718400000)/, where the number represents the milliseconds since epoch/Unix time.  I display the schedules in a Calendar/Week/or Day view, which requires a lot of javascript datetime comparisons.

Anyway, anyone know the correct way to do what I need to do?  I'm thinking I need to store the datetimes as UTC, but I also need to know the timezone where the user's work shift will take place, and then I need to adjust it on the C# side, but then do I need to do anything on the javascript side?

I'm just confused, seems like too many variables to wrap my head around at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on right track.

First rule of thumb for any web application which is accessed in multiple time zones is to store time in UTC format because the primary advantage of storing date/time values in UTC is that it makes the data transportable by providing a universal point of reference by which all time zones are offsetted from.

In your case it would be best store the user timezone so you can render the time based on this information.

When you read UTC date/Time and user time zone, you can calculate this directly in your C# code and pass this data as regular string to your view or because this is actually used a data not date for your users. If you are using JS don't do something like as below because it will set the time based on user browser locale instead i would say just pass as string:

```
var datetime = new Date('May 29, 2012 2:52 AM UTC');
var formattedDateTime = dt.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: Thanks Avkash.  I wound up doing what you suggested, partially at least.  I changed my code to treat all dates as being in the UTC timezone.  So when a user in New York or California enters the date "6/1/2012 10:00AM", it is stored as "6/1/2012 10:00AM UTC", basically overriding the user's timezone.  I changed my javascript to always convert the date to UTC format as well, and everything seems to be working as I desire.  And there's nothing preventing me from displaying the date in the user's local time in the future.